# Ruby on Rails sending emails to users on AD using omniauth-ldap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise, ldap

I'm completely new to Ruby on Rails and I have to build an email system which first uses the company's ID and the omniauth LDAP plugin to login (I already have all the credentials). I also have a project with a form already made. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have an email sent out to specific people once the user logs in and fills out a form . So far all the tutorials I've come across deal only with sending an automatic confirmation email to the user who has created the profile but that's not what I need at all. I have no need for the application to create a new user whatsoever but only wants to send a html/text template I've created to the specified emails. I'm not sure which files code to supply, this is my first time using stackoverflow to ask questions so I apologize in advance for not giving all the correct information. I'm using devise to create the user model. I can supply any files codes necessary and if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be great!

my gemfile looks as such:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-ldap', :git => 'https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-ldap.git'




# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read                                                                                     more:            https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So which step you are lost at? Here are the things to do with email sending:

1. Create a controller, an action and a corresponding route responsible for processing the information inputted into a form by a logged in user. At this step you should get all the inputted data inside of your action in params variable.
2. Create a mailer class (more on this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)) which sends emails to desired receivers using provided html template.
3. Initiate email delivery from your action created at step 1. You should pass the params obtained from a form to mailer (in case that params should be displayed in a resulting email message).

You should also remember that development environment does not send any emails by default. Their text is displayed in your server console. Have a look at "Action Mailer Configuration" section of [the same tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration) to get the idea of doing with it. As an option, you can save email files to your local folder using

```
:delivery_method => :file
```